# Trivial string parse algorithm

Tags: c++, parsing, optimization

In this code example I use a const ref to a vector and check conditions in four functions. If there were a large list of each of the conditions (e.g. all the verbs in a database (e.g. an english dictionary), would it be better to check that in a class Token before passing to the function (so the function simply gets the value verb) OR better to check within the function (so the function itself has to check the database)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool full_stop_check(vector<string> &sentence);
bool verb_check(vector<string> &sentence, int index);
bool noun_check(vector<string> &sentence, int index);
bool conj_arti_check(vector<string> &sentence, int index);

int main ()
{
    vector<string> sentence;
    string temp_word;
    while(cin >> temp_word)
    {
        sentence.push_back(temp_word);
    }
    // Output test (commented out)
    // for (string x : sentence)
    //   cout << x << '\n';

    // Check for sentence
    if (full_stop_check(sentence))
        cout << "It is a sentence." << '\n';
    else
        cout << "It is not a sentence." << '\n';
    return 0;
}
bool full_stop_check(vector<string> &sentence)
{
    int index = sentence.size()-1;
    // Full Stop Check
    if (sentence[index] != ".")
        return false;
    --index;
    if (index < 0 )
        return false;
    return verb_check(sentence, index);         // full stop (not first character)
}
bool verb_check(vector<string> &sentence, int index)
{
    // Verb Check
    if (sentence[index] != "verb")
        return false;
    --index;
    if (index < 0 )
        return false;
    return noun_check(sentence, index);         // verb (not first word)
}
bool noun_check(vector<string> &sentence, int index)
{
    // Noun Check
    if (sentence[index] != "noun")
        return false;
    --index;
    if (index < 0 )                             // first word is a noun
        return true;
    return conj_arti_check(sentence, index);    // noun (not first word)
}
bool conj_arti_check(vector<string> &sentence, int index)
{   
    // Conjugation & Article Check
    if (sentence[index] != "conjugation" && sentence[index] != "article")
        return false;

    // If it is either an article or conjugation
    if (index == 0 && sentence[index] == "article") // first word is an article
        return true;
    else if (index == 0)                            // first word not article (or noun)
        return false;   
    else if (sentence[index] == "conjugation") {    // conjugation
        --index;        
        return verb_check(sentence, index);
    }
    else {                                          // article (not first word)
        --index;
        return conj_arti_check(sentence, index);    // recursion
    }
}
```

Comment: _It is compiling and working okay,_...  _Is it an elegant solution_?  What exactly are you looking for?  Consensus based on opinion only in an open forum is impossible.

Comment: Is there anything specific you want to improve?

Comment: Very true, I guess I was wondering if it is worth working backwards on the sentence. It could be done forwards, but, if it was used to parse multiple sentences it could bite them off one by one this way. I am not precisely sure what I am looking for, just a useful comment or two. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory beyond context free language recognizers is usually based on the [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) (state machine with recursion). It is quite tedious to deal with it by hand but easy to automate so there exist quite a few of parser generators like yacc, ANTLR or BOOST Spirit. They just take language grammar and generate corresponding parser code.